# How can I get a copy of all the information about me that the French tax authorities send to the US tax authorities?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, france, permanent-resident

One of my French banks informed me of the following:

[image]

How can I get a copy of all the information about me that the French tax authorities send to the US tax authorities? (all the information = not just pertaining to my activities with the above-mentioned bank)

Comment: Do they have something similar to FOIA in France? Otherwise I'd go with full account transcript and assume all of it is shared.

Comment: @littleadv They have GDPR... that's probably the direction I'd go (CNIL for France, I believe), but don't know how exactly to go about doing that, so won't answer explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to request your tax transcript information (specifically your Wage & Income Transcript) from the IRS. For instance, I once had an issue with a former employer not sending me a W-2 and 1099, and I was able to obtain the information from my IRS transcript in order to file accurately. You can find more about how to go about requesting it [here](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript). These days you can do it via the IRS website in addition to corresponding with the agency by mail, although doing so will require setting up an online account with the IRS first.

Answer (score -1):

"The information on this form is submitted to the French tax authorities. This information will then be sent by them to the American Tax authorities."

As long as you aren't scribbling the form while blindfolded, you know exactly what is being sent to the IRS, as it is right in front of you.

Comment: While I *generally* agree with this answer, the question does ask "all information" not just the information from that form.